# C++ naming: read_input() vs. readInput()

Tags: c++, naming-conventions

Which naming convention is more preferable in C++? The *underscore* method or the *camelCase* method?
I have coded in Java for a while and I am used to the camelCase naming conventions. 
Which one is more prevalent?

Also, while defining a class, is there any preferred ordering of private/public/protected variables/methods?
Are friends usually put in the end?
What about typedefs, do they come at the top of the class definition?

Comment: Just wanted to add, I would mark this as community wiki and subjective.

Comment: A duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1776291/function-names-in-c-capitalize-or-not even if the title is a little different.

Comment: Most likely a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=c%2B%2B+convention

There are tons of these threads.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

This is all very subjective, but generally for C++ I do:

`camelCase` for functions and variables.

`PascalCase` for classes.

```
public:
protected:
private:
```

In classes.

Edit: Forgot these 2:

Yes, `friend` at the end, `typedef` either at the beginning if they are used in the class, or after if they use the class (for obvious reasons).

Comment: I'd say the same. I tend not to use friends much though - in c++ that is ;)

Comment: @Steven - I hope you don't use your friends in real life.  8v)

Comment: Well I just avoid friends in general :)

Comment: I think you meant PascalCase for classes

Comment: Regarding camelCase, things like `std::vector<...>.push_back()` are rubbing my OCD the wrong way.

Comment: i only used pascalcase for template parameters

Comment: Bjarne stroustrup himself used snake_case in his book. :)

Answer (score 57):

I prefer to take the boost route, and match the standard library. That means `lower_case_names`. I like that my code reads consistent with respect to the STL.

Comment: I used to do that as well, but one project I worked on said that following that sometimes makes it hard to instantly pick out which code you wrote and which is from std:: if you do using namespace std;

That made sense to me, but upvote for you sir as I like this style as well.

Comment: @Adam: so why would it be desirable to differentiate optically between STL code and own code? That never made sense to me, yet people use it in all kinds of environments (not only C++). That’s what *namespaces* are there for – and they do incredibly good work.

Comment: @Konrad: Yes I understand that, but sometimes you don't want to use std:: or myown:: in front of everything, so you use using namespace ...

Then as you go along, you see `something.push_back(item)` then `something.sort()` is this std::list::sort(), or myown::objectwithalist::sort()?

Again, I was forced to follow this at one time, and it has slowly replaced my own standard methods.

Comment: Why not just type `std::`? It solves the problem, and increases readability.

Comment: @GMan: Because I can't write other peoples code, and coding standards take precedence over my personal preference.

Answer (score 7):

The most important thing here is that you stay consistent.  If you are incorporating other people's code into your project, stick with whatever method they were using.  If you are planning on contributing this code to, say, an open-source software project in the future, try to abide by their coding conventions.  If you are writing all of your own code from scratch, I would say stick with the conventions that you are accustomed to using.  This will especially help when you come back to your code later and try to understand what you wrote.

Regarding structure/class access specifications, you will typically see public members listed first, followed by protected then private (in order of increasing access control).  This is done mainly for readability reasons.  When other people are using your code it will be these public members that they will be interfacing with, so placing them at the top of the declaration makes them easier to find.  Ordering members in this fashion keeps the most likely to be used information closest to the top.  I don't see `friend` used all too often, so I can't recall any patterns as to its usage.  `typedef` usually appears at the top so that when looking through the rest of the class, the reader already has an understanding of your custom types (also for readability reasons, `typedef`s are typically grouped together and not interspersed with member declarations).

There are a number of existing coding conventions out there in common use, and the one thing they have in common is a standard.  Whatever system you go with, even if you define it yourself, it helps if you have a document (or a page of example code) outlining the coding convention.  Consistency improves readability, especially when you are revisiting older code at some time in the future.

Here are a couple coding conventions to perhaps give you some ideas:

- [Linux kernel coding style](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.14/process/coding-style.html)
- [OpenTracker coding guidelines](http://www.opentracker.be/guidelines.html)
- [Google's C++ style guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/cppguide.html)
- [id Software's C++ coding conventions](http://www.geeks3d.com/20081111/id-software-c-coding-conventions/)
  (December 2017: the pdf with coding conventions is no longer available.)
- [Rice University coding standard](http://www.cs.rice.edu/~dwallach/CPlusPlusStyle.html)

Answer (score 6):

I usually respect the traditions of the platform/environment I'm programming in, except on multiplatform C/C++ projects where I'm neutral. When programming C++ for Win32 platform, I tend to use the hungarian-notation for variables (type or semantic-prefixes). When programming MFC m_ member variables, etc. The only thing that I cannot get easy in my eyes is the Unix/POSIX `open_device_driver` convention versus `openDeviceDriver` camelcase style.

Answer (score 4):

underscores are often more prevalent on unix or cross platform code.

windows code tends to be camel cased

generally public, protected, private is what i would expect - but maybe that is more from my C# time.

Answer (score 1):

Decades of coding as a job gave my fingers some disease. Whenever I use my little finger to press the [SHIFT] key for capital letter, I feel mild pain.

So I came to prefer snake_notation. Using AutoHotKey utility, I assigned [alt]+[space] combination to 'underscore character' of snake. It is little uncomfortable for my thumb to press [alt], but better than using little finger. (Actually [ctrl]+[space] is much better, but VisualStudio uses this combination as intellisense.) Also, I feel it is faster than camelCase.

I desire i-rocks launches new keyboard with 'underscore key' for programmers who prefer snake_notation.

Answer (score 1):

For my own projects I have adopted the [Apple Coding Conventions](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/CodingConventions.html). During my time writing a decent amount of Objective-C code I came to love the self documenting nature of well written Objective-C code and the Cocoa library.

So in C++ I have stuck with the spirit of these conventions because in my opinion they improve readability and on several occasions getting the name right also helped me think through what the code needs to do.

**SCREAMING_SNAKE_CASE:**

FRAMES_PER_SECOND

**PascalCase:**

ClassName

**camelCase:**

descriptiveMethodName()

positionX

**Underscore:**

_isGameOver

#### Private/Protected/Public:

private:

protected:

public:

#### Apple Convention Examples:

> - Clarity and brevity are both important, but clarity should never be sacrificed for brevity.

```
bgColor(r, g, b, a)
```

A little more typing to do but the increase in clarity is usually worth it.

```
backgroundColorWithAlpha(red, green, blue, alpha)
```

> - Avoid names that are ambiguous.

There are too many examples to mention of this, but consider the introductory code examples from nearly any tutorial. Meaningful names increase clarity and reduce programmer error.

```
i vs index
x vs meaningfulName
posX vs positionX
```

I understand there are historical reasons for names like i, x, j, and hWPTR but in my opinion there is no reason to do them and they are awful for teaching.

Microsoft code examples (copied and repeated forever) are some of the worst offenders.

```
szStr
oObj
```

Seriously?!

Of course when collaborating with a team I am happy to adopt whatever the standard is. I want my code to look like it belongs to the project. The one thing that does make me twitch a little are weird braces.

K&R braces are the only correct braces. :)

```
bool hasComponents() {
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I use underscores for local variables; ALL_UPPERCASE for macros and constants; camelCase for nothing and CamelCase for everything else.

I always use structs and never classes, and thus start with public: (without specifying it) and then put private: at the end.

This is all very subjective and there is no right or wrong answer.

Answer (score 0):

> Which naming convention is more
>   preferable in C++? The `underscore'
>   method or the camelCase method? I have
>   coded in Java for a while and I am
>   used to the camelCase naming
>   conventions. Which one is more
>   prevalent?

I'd say 'just stick with what you know on this if you are starting to write your own libraries', they are both used regularly.

> Also, while defining a class, is there any preferred ordering of private/public/protected variables/methods?

This varies by programmer/team. I order by category. I use a category for 'internal/private methods', and that category is generally second to last (the last being prohibited implementation).

> Are friends usually put in the end?

I use them rarely; I insert them above the dependency (method), otherwise, after the constructor/destructor category.

> What about typedefs, do they come at the top of the class definition?

That is where I put them.

If you want to get into details, there are publicly available coding conventions. Since you already have a Java background, you'll easily be able to cut through the 'taste' in them.

Answer (score 0):

If some languages come with naming conventions (e.g., https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/ for python), this is not the case in C++.

This might be linked with B. Stroustrup (the creator of C++) "disliking monoculture" (https://youtu.be/ZQds2aGHwDA?t=169).

Even the standards of c++ follows different naming convention (Thriving in a Crowded and Changing World: C++ 2006–2020, part 6.5 Naming of concepts). I don't think there is a prevalent style in the C++ community; I have not found statistics but different companies use very different styles.

As suggested by Freek de Bruijn, the key is **consistency**. If the project you are working on follows a convention, stick to it.
If not, follow one of the existing convention suggested in Freek's post/ it would be easier than inventing your own.