# "onEachSubelement(...)" method for C++

Tags: c++, c++11, containers

I often pack some data into `class` to prevent mistakes with public/global access and to provide some common methods on it, e.g.:

```
class GameArea{
    std::vector<Enemy*> enemies;
    std::wstring name;
public:
    void makeAllEnemiesScared();
    Enemy * getEnemy(unsigned index);
};
```

**`GameArea` is just an simplified example here.** It'd a kind of custom container/menager with some specialized methods (but it's not only an container).

The ideal situation is when I know what operations will be executed on each `Enemy` at once and they occur in several places so I can declare them in `GameArea` directly (like `makeAllEnemiesScared()`).

For other cases I can go with:

```
for(unsigned i=0; i<gameArea->getEnemiesCount(); i++){
    Enemy * enemy = gameArea->getEnemy(i);
    ...
}
```

But **it suffers from some disadvantages**:

- I cannot use C++11 clean&nice `for(auto &Enemy : enemies)` loop,
- It's not efficient (so many calls to `getEnemy(index)`),
- It's not a purpose for `getEnemy(index)` to iterate throw all elements - it's usefull in case when we want to select single or few of them, it also has check for `index < enemies.size()` inside - it's terrible to check it on each element in loop.

**NOTE:** I think about cases when I do something very special (**not worth creating separated method in `GameArea`**, but **on each element** of `GameArea::enemies`).

I thought about some `GameArea::onEachEnemy(... function ...)` method that takes a `function` (or maybe better an lambda?) as a parameter. Is that good solution?

Or maybe **different approach should be used here? Like returning the `std::vector` from `GameArea`** - which looks a bit "ugly" to me. I don't want user to think he can actually add or remove items to/from that `vector` directly.

Comment: Your "onEachEnemy" suggestion sounds good to me.

Comment: I'm assuming that all `getEnemy` does is to return `enemies[i]`? Then you can inline the function and the compiler will most likely optimize the call away. You can also avoid the repeated `getEnemiesCount` call by calling it before the loop and saving the result. You can also provide an iterator interface, or, like you wonder, create a "for each" function. But first of all you should probably profile your program to see if this really is the bottle-neck you think it is.

Comment: Oh, and remember that the vector `operator[]` function doesn't do any bounds-checking, it assumes the user of the vector will take care to not go out of bounds. If you're so worried about inefficiency then you should probably do the same, i.e. drop the bounds checking from `getEnemy`. But like I said in my previous comment, *profile* first, and make sure this really is as inefficient as you think it is.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg it does a bit more: `if(i>=enemies.size()){ return 0;} return enemies[i]`. But I did not think about compiler optimization and moving the `getEnemiesCount` before the loop, thanks :)

Comment: Even so, inlining the function might still help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A good solution which does not expose internals of your classes is, as you suggested, a function calling an action for each object:

```
class GameArea {
 ...
  template<typename Func> void ForEachEnemy(Func f)
  {
    std::for_each(enemies.begin(), enemies.end(), f);
  }
 ...
```

Then you can pass anything you want as `ForEachEnemy` argument - global function, `boost::bind` result etc.

Comment: I finally went with that option, but for all the readers - check out ALL the responds because the proposed solutions (exposing vector itself, exposing begin/end iterator, using `has a` instead of `is a` relation) are good and may suit better to your own situation :)

Answer (score 4):

If you expose the vector itself, or at least iterators `begin` and `end`, you can use [`std::for_each`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each)

Then you would use this as

```
std::for_each(std::begin(enemies), std::end(enemies), foo);
```

where foo is the function you want to call on each `Enemy`.

Again note you don't have to expose the vector itself, you could make methods in `GameArea` to get iterators so the call could be like

```
std::for_each(gameArea->GetEnemyBegin(), gameArea->GetEnemyEnd(), foo);
```

Comment: That's quite a smart alternative for my `GameArea::onEachEnemy(... function ...)`, thank you :) I will wait a bit for other responds to give a chance to get more ideas, but I've already up-voted it.

Comment: Note that if you [expose iterators in the right way](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8164567/how-to-make-my-custom-type-to-work-with-range-based-for-loops) it will work with C++11 ranged-based for loops as well.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to consider the [Iterator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterator_pattern) pattern. That way you can keep the encapsulation but still have something that is convenient to use.

You can either expose standard container iterators or if you want complete encapsulation, write the Iterator yourself. If you write the Iterator correctly you can even use C++11 range-based for loops:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

struct Enemy{ std::string name; };

class EnemyIterator {
  friend class GameArea;
private:
  std::vector<Enemy>::iterator iterator;
  EnemyIterator(std::vector<Enemy>::iterator it) : iterator(it){}
public:
  EnemyIterator& operator++() { ++iterator; return *this; }
  Enemy& operator*() { return *iterator; }
  friend bool operator!=(EnemyIterator lhs, EnemyIterator rhs) {
    return lhs.iterator != rhs.iterator;
  }
};

class GameArea{
  std::vector<Enemy> enemies;
public:   
  EnemyIterator begin() { return EnemyIterator(enemies.begin()); }
  EnemyIterator end() { return EnemyIterator(enemies.end()); } 
  void addEnemy(std::string name) {enemies.push_back(Enemy{name}); }
};

int main() {
    GameArea area;
    area.addEnemy("Kobold");
    area.addEnemy("Wraith");
    area.addEnemy("Ork");
    for (auto& enemy : area)
      std::cout << enemy.name << "\n";
}
```

In order for C++11 ranged-based for loops to work with `GameArea` you need to do one of:

- define begin and end member functions
- define begin and end non-member functions in the same namespace
- specialize std::begin and std::end