# What are the qualifications for a class in C++ to become a container?

Tags: c++, containers

I'm new to C++ programming and came across the term `containers` with examples such as `vector`, `deque`, `map`, etc.

What should be the minimum requirements that a `class` should fulfill to be called a `container` in C++?

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Container

Comment: basic knowledge of templates, class, typedef and alias, iterators, knows to use an array and iterators are mininum  there are two container types sequential and associative containers

Comment: For beginners, standard containers is not something to invent & create, it is stuff to know and to (often) use *wisely* (choosing the right one). So you can understand [containers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container) as being the one *provided* by the C++ standard library. You won't make new containers (at least, not as a newbie), you'll use existing ones. Then the containers are *only* the one provided by the C++ standard library (when you'll be able to code your own generic templated containers, you won't be a C++ newbie,  but a guru)

Comment: As @StoryTeller says there is a basic container concept that all containers adhere to. But usually they also adapt other concepts like [Sequence Container](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/SequenceContainer) to provide more functionality.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I will start with the concept Range.

Range has only two methods -- begin and end.  They both return iterators of the same type (note: there are proposals to permit end to return a Sentinel instead).

Iterators are presumed to be understood by the reader.

A high quality Range can also expose empty, size, front, back, and operator [] (if random access especially).

For a `for(:)` loop, you can qualify as a `Range` by being a raw C array, having `begin()` and `end()` methods, or having free functions in the same namespace as your type that take your type as one argument (and return iterator-like things).  As of this post, the only thing in the standard that consumes Ranges is `for(:)` loops.  One could argue that [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31457319/1774667) is the only practical definition of the concept Range in C++.

---

Next, Container.

A Container is a Range of at least forward iterators (input and output Ranges are usually not called Containers) that owns its elements.  Sequential and Associative containers are different beasts, and both are defined in the standard.

Containers in the standard have a set of typedefs -- value type, iterator, const iterator.  Most also have allocator (except array).  They have empty, and most have size (except forward_list).

Containers can all be constructed by 2 input or forward iterators to a compatible value type, and from an initializer list.

Sequential containers have push and emplace back (except forward list) (and some have emplace/push front), and insert and emplace at iterator (or after for forward list).

Associative containers have a key type.  Many of them are containers of pairs.  The data stored is usually partially const (the "key" part of the data, be it the key or the entire field in the case of `set`s).  They have insert and emplace with and without hints -- they manage their own order.  They also have a `.find` and `.count` methods.

There are currently no functions in the std library that depend on Container-ness.  And there is an active proposal to make Container-ness and Range-ness be formalized as a concept in C++17.  The actual technical definition of Container is in the standard in case you need to create an actual container exactly; however, usually you really need a Range with a means to edit it and ownership mechanics.  The Container concept is, in my experience, mostly there to make specifying behaviour easier in the standard.

After something like Ranges-v3 is added, the concepts of Range and Container will be actual things that exist in code, and there may be algorithms that depend on exactly those features.  Prior to that, they are ad-hoc concepts more than anything.

Answer (score 2):

The **absolute minimum** requirement should be that the container has a constant iterator class associated with it.  Although a generator would satisfy that requirement as well.  So it must be that there is a constant iterator and that the said container has *begin* and *end* values of the constant iterator type.

Answer (score 1):

> ### C++ concepts: Container
>
> A Container is an object used to store other objects and taking care
>   of the management of the memory used by the objects it contains.
>
> http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Container

> A container is a holder object that stores a collection of other
>   objects (its elements). They are implemented as class templates, which
>   allows a great flexibility in the types supported as elements.
>
> http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/

Given these definitions, I think we can say that containers should be able to store an arbitrary number of elements (although the number can be a compile-time constant). The container owns the objects it contains, including allocating space for them in the heap, or the stack (for the `array` container). Therefore, the programmer does not need to `new` or `delete` (allocate or free) the memory for the objects.

The following containers can be found in the STL: array, deque, vector, set, map, stack, queue, list, unordered_map, unordered_set

The container will usually allow you to access (or index) the elements it contains, although some only allow access to one or a few elements (eg. queue or stack). The container will provide methods to add or remove objects, or to search for an object.

#### Requirements:

- Must hold some arbitrary number of objects
- The objects it holds are an arbitrary type (although it may have to satisfy certain requirements, eg. sortable)

#### Possible features

- While some containers are allocator aware, it does not have to be.
- A container may hold more than one type of object (eg. map, although map can be considered to hold pairs of objects)
- While containers may be iterable, this is not required, eg. queue or stack.

#### Classes which are containers

- **std::string**: this is a collection of characters. Although is designed for characters, or wide-characters, it is a [SequenceContainer](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/SequenceContainer)

#### Some class which would not be considered containers:

- **std::unique_ptr, std::shared_ptr**: while these types have a concept of ownership, they only manage 1 object, so they are not a collection of objects
- **std::tuple, std::pair**: while a tuple can hold an arbitrary number of objects, the type of each object needs to be specified, so it doesn't have the flexibility expected of a general container. A tuple can be more accurately categorized as a type of structure.

Comment: That is indeed a good reference (the first one). However merely copying it, without realizing the requirements you copied are vapid, is not a good answer.

Comment: would you please mind explaining things in detail rather than merely copying things.

Comment: The "requirements" you quoted are not actually the requirements given in the link. They are only the legend used to understand the requirements.