# type_traits - contiguous memory

Tags: c++, c++11

I have an interface that deals with any container type. `std::vector`, `std::array`, and even `std::basic_string`. The issue is that there is nothing to prevent someone from passing a container that does not have continguous memory.

The current solution I have is to `delete` those interface I want to prevent.

```
void dosoemthing(const std::list&)=delete;
void dosoemthing(const std::map&)=delete;
```

However, I would prefer if I could just add a static assertion based on the type trait. Which leads to my question. Does their exist a type trait for containers that can be used to identify if its memory is contiguous? I have been coming through the [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/type_traits) and have yet to find anything. I figured before marking it a lost cause I would check with the A team.

Comment: [What are the qualifications for a class in C++ to become a container?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33064590/what-are-the-qualifications-for-a-class-in-c-to-become-a-container)

Comment: @0x499602D2 That doesn't answer the question at all. A `std::map` is a container but one of the container types the OP explicitly wants to exclude from the set of overloads because it doesn't guarantee contiguous memory.

Comment: @leemes I see. My mistake.

Comment: Just for your information: it seems that C++17 will have a concept for that (Of course you still need something for C++11, but I wanted to tell you that for C++17 we probably have a standard way to check that.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can bring your own type trait, and then use `static_assert` to verify it:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <vector>
#include <array>
#include <string>


template<typename T>
struct has_contiguous_memory : std::false_type {};

template<typename T, typename U>
struct has_contiguous_memory<std::vector<T, U>> : std::true_type {};

template<typename T>
struct has_contiguous_memory<std::vector<bool, T>> : std::false_type {};

template<typename T, typename U, typename V>
struct has_contiguous_memory<std::basic_string<T, U, V>> : std::true_type {};

template<typename T, std::size_t N>
struct has_contiguous_memory<std::array<T, N>> : std::true_type {};

template<typename T>
struct has_contiguous_memory<T[]> : std::true_type {};

template<typename T, std::size_t N>
struct has_contiguous_memory<T[N]> : std::true_type {};
```

Comment: I'd make the `vector` version also accept a non-default allocator (its second template argument; just add another one). Besides that, you could rewrite the last three specializations as one which accepts any container which iterator is a pointer type. That would include all three versions, but also include other containers, but maybe also potentially containers that use a pointer type for the iterator but don't guarantee contiguous memory? (I'm not sure if the last is true)

Comment: @leemes Good point, thanks! I've just fixed specialization for `std::vector`. Concerning the latter: I would keep existing checks, because they are more explicit.

Comment: Yeah it probably is the better way. Also, I couldn't verify my guess that `std::array::iterator` is always a pointer (it seems it doesn't have to be).

Comment: I have followed the same approach [here](https://github.com/iavr/xio/blob/master/c%2B%2B/config.hpp), where I needed such a trait for low-level input/output. As you see, you can include `std::basic_string` and exclude `std::vector<bool>`.