# Range-for loop with custom class(simple version of vector<string>,using allocator)

Tags: c++

I'm currently going through C++ Primer 5th Ed. and today I've reached the chapter about classes that deal with dynamic memory. Given, the following concept:

```
class StrVec{

  public:

    StrVec() : // the allocator member is default initialized
      elements(nullptr),
      first_free(nullptr),
      cap(nullptr) {}

    StrVec(const StrVec&);

    StrVec(std::initializer_list<std::string>);

    StrVec& operator=(const StrVec&);

    ~StrVec();
    std::string*        begin()     const       { return elements; }
    std::string*        end()       const       { return first_free; }
    //other functions

  private:

    std::allocator<std::string> alloc; 

    std::string *elements; 

    std::string *first_free; 

    std::string *cap;

    //other functions

};
```

And a `StrVec` object `StrVec foo={"stack","overflow"}`, how does a range-for loop work exactly (`for(auto& el : foo) std::cout<<el<<std::endl`). What's the "thing" that I'm iterating through?

Comment: Are you asking about dynamic memory allocation, or about [range for loops](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for)?

Comment: You've omitted the key member functions required for the range for loop... What are you actually asking?

Comment: Something about an answer to this question.

Comment: @LogicStuff The implementation is not what I'm asking about. The loop works just fine. Take it like this, if it was the vector I would've been iterating through, it goes ---> v[0],v[1],v[2].. etc, but what am I iterating through in a StrVec object ? You can't use the subscript, obviously, nor do I have a container in the class

Comment: What is it, then?

Comment: @JohhnieWH Without at least the declarations of a `begin()` and `end()` there's no way of telling what a [range-based for loop](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) over `StrVec` would do (except cause compilation errors).

Comment: @Biffen Oh, so the loop is using these ?` std::string* begin()  const  { return elements; }
 std::string*  end()  const  { return first_free; }` // sorry for poor editing but it's the first time I use this site

Comment: **Dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8164567/how-to-make-my-custom-type-to-work-with-range-based-for-loops**

Comment: @JohhnieWH Where did those come from?! Can you see now why we're asking to see more code?

Comment: @Biffen Sorry, I thought it would be enough, I put them in the original post too, they were included in `//other functions`

Comment: Your question's title is pretty terrible. Fix it please!

Comment: Nope, still doesn't describe the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What's the "thing" that I'm iterating through?

The range that is delimited by the result of `foo.begin()` and `foo.end()`.

Yes, these function names are "special" in that regard. Call it a standard-approved convention.

Comment: Thanks for the answers @Biffen and Lightnesss Races in Orbit, I got it now :D