# c++ - Which way to search for elements in a container is more efficient

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I'm just iterating/subscripting for values inside a container or string to see if those values are what I want. I just want to know which way (between numbers1 and numbers2) is more efficient.

```
bool isnumber (const char character)
{
    return(character>=48 && character<=57);             
}

template <typename T> bool numbers1(const T &str)
{
    if(!str.empty())
    {
        for (auto it=str.cbegin(); it!=str.cend(); ++it) if (!isnumber(*it)) return false;

        return true;
    }
    else return false;
}

template <typename T> bool numbers2(const T &str)
{
    if(!str.empty())
    {
        for (auto &i : str) if(!isnumber(i)) return false;

        return true;
    }
    else return false;
}
```

Comment: Just use [std::find](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find)

Comment: @JesperJuhl Or even better, use `std::any_of`.

Comment: And use `isdigit()` instead of implementing it yourself.  But if you do implement it yourself, use `'0'` instead of 48.

Comment: @juanchopanza Thanks, didn't know about that

Comment: @JohnZwinck I don't like to use isdigit() simply because it throws an exception every time I send a character that is not in range (-1 to 255), for example Ñ.

Answer (score 0):

Range-based for loops in C++ are essentially just shorthand for a loop that uses begin() and end() generally with iterators.  In numbers2, the compiler expands the loop to use str.begin and str.end.  The only real difference on a compiled level is that your handwritten iterator loop uses cbegin() and cend() instead of begin() and end().

Just further reading: If you make a class that implements begin() and end() then you will be able to perform range-based for loops on that class: [How to make my custom type to work with "range-based for loops"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8164567/how-to-make-my-custom-type-to-work-with-range-based-for-loops)

Comment: "The only real difference on a compiled level is that your handwritten iterator loop uses cbegin() and cend() instead of begin() and end()" - and the fact that range-for only checks the end condition once whereas a classic for loop tests it on each iteration.

Comment: So that means that range-for loops should not alter the container due to the fact than end() can be invalidated because of it?