# Iterator adaptor to hide structure detail

Tags: c++, boost, c++14

Assume we have the following:

```
struct MyClass {
   typedef vector<MyValue> InnerVector;
   const InnerVector & get() { ... }
};

vector<MyClass> classes;
```

Is there a way to provide a "flattened" iterator over `classes`? That is to view `classes` as if its some list of `InnerVector`. Each dereference of the iterator is expected to return an `InnerVector`. Something like the following:

```
auto all_inner_vectors = magic_iterator(classes);
for (auto inner_vector : all_inner_vectors) {
  ...
}
```

It seems that boost iterator adaptors could be handy here. But I could not figure out what adaptors would fit this purpose.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] in the sense that the structure of your class is defined. Even though your intent is understandable, it is hard to give anything concrete unless there is a well-defined problem

Comment: You should create a class wrapping `classes` and exposing functionality to obtain a custom `inner vector iterator`. Example of writing something like that: https://gist.github.com/jeetsukumaran/307264

Comment: And here an awesome answer on how to make it range-based for loop aware https://stackoverflow.com/a/31457319/3754223

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With [range-v3](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3), you may do

```
for (MyValue& value : myClass.get() | ranges::view::join) {
    // ...
}
```

Or you might change your class to use join directly:

```
struct MyClass {
   using InnerVector = vector<MyValue>;

   // Return a range of MyValue.
   auto get() { return InnerVector | ranges::view::join; }
};
```

And then

```
for (MyValue& value : myClass.get()) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Though it doesn't directly answer my question (I wanted to iterate on a vector of MyClass, not on the inner vector), but I found range-v3 to perfectly fit my needs. Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: @Oups, indeed, not applied the join at the correct level. You need `classes | range::view::transform(&MyClass::get) | range::view::join`.