# Cannot use range-for loop for a custom type inside a template function - C++

Tags: c++

I am trying to create a template function that can sum the values of a container. I try to use it to sum the values of a Vector (defined by me). However, VS is giving me following errors:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C3312    no callable 'end' function found for type 'const TContainer'
        with
        [
            TContainer=Vector<int>
        ]   Test    C:\Data\Development\C++\Test\Test\Test.cpp  221 
Error   C2065    'item': undeclared identifier  Test    C:\Data\Development\C++\Test\Test\Test.cpp  222 
Error   C3312    no callable 'begin' function found for type 'const TContainer'
        with
        [
            TContainer=Vector<int>
        ]   Test    C:\Data\Development\C++\Test\Test\Test.cpp  221
```

For learning purposes, I re-implemented my own Vector container. I created `T* begin(Vector<T>&)` and `T* end(Vector<T>&)`. I also implemented

Using for-range loop outside a template function for my Vector works fine. Also, using my sum function for std::vector works fine. It is only using my sum function with my Vector gives the error.

```cpp
// header
template<typename T>
class Vector {
private:
    T* elements;
    int size;
public:
    Vector(int size);
    int getSize() {
        return size; 
    }
    T& operator[](int index);
};
```

```cpp
// implementation
template<typename T>
Vector<T>::Vector(int size) :
    elements(new T[size]),
    size(size) {}

template<typename T>
T& Vector<T>::operator[](int index) {
    return elements[index];
}

template<typename T>
T* begin(Vector<T>& vec) {
    if (vec.getSize() > 0) {
        return &vec[0];
    } else {
        return nullptr;
    }
}

template<typename T>
T* end(Vector<T>& vec) {
    return begin(vec) + vec.getSize();
}
```

```cpp
// sum
template<typename TContainer, typename TValue>
TValue sum(const TContainer& container, TValue init) {
    for (auto item : container) {
        init += item;
    }
    return init;
}
```

```cpp
// Test code
int main() {
    Vector<int> a(5);

    a[0] = 1;
    a[1] = 10;
    a[2] = 3;
    a[3] = 100;
    a[4] = -200;

    for (int item : a) {
        std::cout << item << "\n"; // This works fine.
    }

    std::cout << sum(std::vector<int>{1, 2, 3}, 0); // This also works fine.

    std::cout << sum(a, 0); // This gives me the above error.

}
```

---

## Solution

<s>Since this question is very irresponsibly marked as duplicate, I have to post the fixed code in the problem to avoid "I figured it out" memes.</s>

The main issue is that the signature of C style `begin` `end` is `const T* begin(const Vector<T>&)` and `const T* end(const Vector<T>&)`. (I don't know why const is only required in template `range-for`s but not regular `range-for`s though.)

```cpp
template<typename T>
const T* begin(const Vector<T>& vec) { // <-- CHANGED
    if (vec.getSize() > 0) {
        return &vec[0];
    } else {
        return nullptr;
    }
}

template<typename T>
const T* end(const Vector<T>& vec) { // <-- CHANGED
    return begin(vec) + vec.getSize();
}
```

Now, VS gives another set of errors complaining about not const.

```cpp
// header
template<typename T>
class Vector {
private:
    T* elements;
    int size;
public:
    Vector(int size);
    int getSize() const { // <-- CHANGED, made it return a const
        return size; 
    }
    T& operator[](int index);
    const T& operator[](int index) const; // <-- ADDED, so there is a const version of the [] operator.
};
```

Now implementing the added const [] operator:

```cpp
// ADDED TO implementation
template<typename T>
const T& Vector<T>::operator[](int index) const {
    return elements[index];
}
```

Now the code works.

Never mind, I was wrong. My approach is entirely wrong. You need to hand write 12 functions in order to make sure `range-for` loops work. See the duplicate question for information.

Comment: `begin()` and `end()` should be class members.

Comment: The cause of your error is that you're missing `const T* begin(const Vector<T>&)` (and same for `end`).

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Nope, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8164567/how-to-make-my-custom-type-to-work-with-range-based-for-loops), function or class member should both work. Also, please note, using a range-for outside the template function works.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm But your comment nor the duplicate question you marked answer the question that why it only does not work inside a template function but works fine outside. Honestly, I do not think this is the problem.

Comment: `begin` and `end` are defined for `std::vector`.  You're lacking the definitions for `const` objects for your custom `Vector` type.  (The `for` loop works without the const, the second working use uses `std::vector`, the third fails because of your missing definitions.)

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm Yes, after adding `const` (and some tweaks to make it is indeed const), it does work now. However, the third one is still using range-for loop. So why it works for the first but not the third?

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm nvm, you are right.