# How to provide multiple begin/end proxies for a class

Tags: c++, iterator, range, c++14, const-correctness

Given the classes

```
struct Data
{
  void bar() const;
  void baz();
}

class Foo
{
  std::vector<Data> data;
  std::map<size_t, Data> indexed_data;
}
```

I'd like to implement something in class Foo so that I can do the following:

```
int main()
{
  Foo foo;

  for(const auto& data : foo.data())
    data.bar();

  for(auto& data : foo.indexed_data())
    data.baz();

  const auto& foo_ref = foo;
  for(auto& data : foo_ref.data())
    data.baz();  // constness violated, shouldn't compile
}
```

However, I don't wanna expose the class internals by just returning references to the containers. I might also work with classes where the range I'd like to iterate over isn't implemented as a container. So I basically want to create some sort of proxy object which is just a little more than a wrapper to a begin/end pair so that I can iterate over multiple things inside my class.
Additionally I would like it to be const correct as displayed above. Is there any well-known pattern to realize this?

Comment: related/dupe on what the proxy should look like: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8164567/how-to-make-my-custom-type-to-work-with-range-based-for-loops

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider three cases.

---

If you want to give full access to your internal data, just make a function to return it: (simply making the member public is also an option)

```
class C {
public:
          Type& data()       { return data_; }
    const Type& data() const { return data_; }
private:
    Type data_;
};
```

---

If you want to give read-only access to your internal data, just drop the non-const overload:

```
class C {
public:
    const Type& data() const { return data_; }
private:
    Type data_;
};
```

---

If you want to give element-only access to your internal data, i.e., you have mutable access to each individual element (when the `C` itself is non-const), but you can't change the container itself (e.g., insert a new element), you need to return a proxy.  Since C++20, we can return a `std::ranges::ref_view`:

```
class C {
public:
    auto data()       { return std::ranges::ref_view(data_); }
    auto data() const { return std::ranges::ref_view(data_); }
private:
    Type data_;
};
```

You can use the [Ranges library](https://ericniebler.github.io/range-v3) if C++20 is not available.  This way, the user can access the individual elements, but cannot change the container itself.

Alternatively, you can write your own (minimalist) proxy:

```
template <typename R>
class Proxy {
public:
    explicit Proxy(R& r) :range{r} {}
    auto begin() const { return range.begin(); }
    auto   end() const { return range.end(); }
private:
    R& range;
};
```

Then you can return `Proxy{data_}`:

```
class C {
public:
    auto data()       { return Proxy{data_}; }
    auto data() const { return Proxy{data_}; }
private:
    Type data_;
};
```

Prior to C++17, you can write it like this without class template argument deduction:

```
class C {
public:
    auto data()       { return Proxy<      Type>{data_}; }
    auto data() const { return Proxy<const Type>{data_}; }
private:
    Type data_;
};
```

Comment: The proxy is pretty much what I've been coming up with but so far I couldn't get it to work. Because to retrieve the proxy via const references or pointers to C I have to make auto data() const (assuming C++20 now). This then means that data_ will also be a const ref within data(), typename R deduces to its underlying type and then I'm trying to construct R& range from a const reference passed to the Proxy ctor. Everything else breaks const-correctness.

Comment: @user1709708 I added the const overload to the answer.  Is it what you are looking for?

Comment: more or less yes, but I can't get this to compile if I use the Proxy object from above (at least not preserving const-correctness). See here https://ideone.com/XE9RUm

Comment: @user1709708 You need to use `Proxy<const Type>{data_}` for the const overload.

Comment: I see. I think the problem with my actual code was that I didn't use auto as return type for the Proxy's begin/end functions but specified the iterator type. That then again led to constness problems as I didn't make it depend on R's constness. Anyway, everything works as expected now, thanks a lot.