# How to make a hierarchy of different object "generators" in plain C++11

Tags: c++, c++11

What I need is the following hierarchy of classes (given here as a sketch):

```
class DataClass {}

class AbstractGenerator {
public:
    // Generates DataClass objects one by one. In a lazy manner
    virtual DataClass produce() = 0;
}

class RandGenerator : AbstractGenerator {
public:
    RandGenerator(int maximal_int) : maximal(maximal_int) {}
    DataClass produce() {
        // get a random number from 0 to this->maximal
        // make a DataClass object from the random int and return it
    }

private:
    int maximal;
}

class FromFileGenerator : AbstractGenerator {
public:
    FromFileGenerator(string file_name) : f_name(file_name) {}
    DataClass produce() {
        // read the next line from the file
        // deserialize the DataClass object from the line and return it
    }

private:
    string f_name;
}
```

What I want to support for both `RandGenerator` and `FromFileGnerator` is:

```
RandGenerator rg();
for (DataClass data : rg) {...}
```

And also some method of taking "first n elements of the generator".

What are the appropriate tools in the plain C++11 that one could use to achieve this, or whatever is the closest to this in C++11?

Comment: To enable range for loops you need to provide iterator for the given class. There are plenty of resources online how to do it. You can also refer to the following question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8164567/how-to-make-my-custom-type-to-work-with-range-based-for-loops

Comment: @JeJo No, that should be a single object that generates other objects. That's how Python generators work, for example.

Comment: @michelson The issue there is that I need to support an abstract class and each of its children would define a specific advancing mechanism. A generic `operator++` would not work. For example, one would read from a PRNG, another would deserialize objects from a file.

Comment: @foki and have you thought about streams to do the job you want? Couse, in my opinion, you can either introduce some collection to keep the data and just iterating over it or, if the size is unknown, use streams. This range for loop thing is this something required or you can just skip it, providing an alternative - stream?

Comment: @michelson What is the difference between iterators and streams in this case?

Comment: This looks like you need a [`boost::function_output_iterator`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/libs/iterator/doc/function_output_iterator.html)

Comment: @michelson: Why in the world would someone use streams in C++ for anything like this?

Comment: You are going to want `AbstractGenerator` to have a way of signalling that it has no more elements. C++ doesn't catch `stop_iteration` to end `for(auto val : range)` like Python does

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`boost::function_input_iterator`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/libs/iterator/doc/function_output_iterator.html) is the normal tool for this job, but since you want "plain" C++, we can just reimplement the same concept.

```
class generator_iterator {
   std::shared_ptr<AbstractGenerator> generator;
public:
   using iterator_category = std::input_iterator_tag;
   generator_iterator(std::shared_ptr<AbstractGenerator> generator_)
       :generator(generator_) {}
   
   DataClass operator*(){return generator->produce();}
   generator_iterator& operator++(){return *this;}
   generator_iterator operator++(int){return *this;}
   //plus all the other normal bits for an output_iterator
};
```

And then in your `AbstractGenerator` class, provide `begin` and `end` methods.

```
generator_iterator begin() {return {this};}
generator_iterator end() {return {nullptr};} //or other logic depending on how you want to detect the end of a series
```

Comment: Why `output_iterator_tag` ... repeatedly calling a function with side effects and using its return value is more like an input iterator, no?

Comment: your `++`s don't work. `generator_iterator& operator++(){return *this;} generator_iterator operator++(int){return *this;}`

Comment: `function_output_iterator` consumes values. I think you mean [`function_input_iterator`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_73_0/libs/iterator/doc/function_input_iterator.html)

Comment: @Caleth: Despite writing thousands of iterators, I always get input/output backwards. The fact that Input produces values, and Output consumes values always baffles me. Thanks, Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Add a `begin` and `end` member function to `AbstractGenerator`, which return iterators which call the `produce` member function.

Such an iterator ([demo](https://ideone.com/GZZliQ)) could look similar to this:

```cpp
template<typename Fn>
struct CallRepeatedlyIterator
{
    using iterator_category = std::input_iterator_tag;
    using value_type = typename std::result_of<Fn()>::type;

    // Not sure if that's correct (probably not):
    using difference_type = unsigned;
    using pointer = value_type *;
    using reference = value_type &;
    
    
    bool is_end;
    union {
        Fn fn;
    };
    union {
        value_type buffer;
    };
    
    value_type operator*() const
    {
        return buffer;
    }
    
    CallRepeatedlyIterator & operator++()
    {
        buffer = fn();
        return *this;
    }
    
    CallRepeatedlyIterator()
    : is_end(true)
    {}
    
    explicit CallRepeatedlyIterator(Fn f)
    : is_end(false)
    {
        new (&fn) Fn(f);
        new (&buffer) value_type(fn());
    }
    
    bool operator==(CallRepeatedlyIterator const & other) const
    {
        return is_end && other.is_end;
    }
    
    bool operator!=(CallRepeatedlyIterator const & other) const
    {
        return !(*this == other);
    }

    // NOTE: A destructor is missing here! It needs to destruct fn and buffer 
    //       if its not the end iterator.
};
```

Now your `begin` member function returns such an iterator which calls `produce` (e.g. using a by reference capturing lambda) and `end` returns an "end" iterator.

This means that your `for` loop would run forever (no way to reach the end iterator)!