# How do I implement an iterable structure?

Tags: c++, loops, struct

I want to write a structure through which I can loop. For this I added two methods begin and end which would return begin, end values of an already existing vector. What return type should I specify, and will these two methods be enough to make MATCH structure work in my context? Here's what I've got so far:

```cpp
typedef std::pair<std::string, std::string> combo;
struct MATCH {
    std::vector<combo> matches;
    ? begin() { return matches.begin(); }
    ? end() { return matches.end(); }
};

int main() {
    MATCH m = { ... };
    for (const combo& i : m)
        ...;
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make my custom type to work with "range-based for loops"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8164567/how-to-make-my-custom-type-to-work-with-range-based-for-loops)

Comment: I recommend using a different container than a `struct`; one that is iterable.  Otherwise, I recommend implementing iterators.  Based on the value of an iteration, you can return the member;  however, in order for this to work, you'll need to have all the members the same types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the type you're looking for is `std::vector<combo>::iterator`.

Example:

```
typedef std::pair<std::string, std::string> combo;
struct MATCH {
    std::vector<combo> matches;
    std::vector<combo>::iterator begin() { return matches.begin(); }
    std::vector<combo>::iterator end() { return matches.end(); }
};


int main()
{
    MATCH m = { { {"something", "something"} } };
    for (const combo& i : m)
        cout << i.first << " " << i.second << std::endl;
   
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Good place to use the keyword `auto`

Comment: Though you might also want `std::vector<combo>::const_iterator begin() const { return matches.begin(); }` and likewise for `end()`. Or in some cases, maybe only the `const` versions.