# binding reference of type const node*& to node*const

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, tree

I am trying to implement a generic tree and in the function `getSizeRecursive` `line 1`why cannot i use `const node* &root`. Similarly, i am getting the same mistake in `line 2`.The compiler is giving an error which i am not able to comprehend.

```
graph.cpp: In function 'int getSizeRecursive(const node*&)':
graph.cpp:56:40: error: binding reference of type 'const node*&' to 'node* const' discards qualifiers
   56 |         for(const node* &child : root->children) // line 2
      |                                        ^~~~~~~~
graph.cpp: In function 'int main()':
graph.cpp:69:36: error: binding reference of type 'const node*&' to 'node*' discards qualifiers
   69 |         cout << getSizeRecursive(t.root) << endl;
      |                                  ~~^~~~
graph.cpp:51:35: note:   initializing argument 1 of 'int getSizeRecursive(const node*&)'
   51 | int getSizeRecursive(const node* &root){ // line 1
      |                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~
[Finished in 2.9s]
```

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <stack>
using namespace std;
class node{
public:
    int data;
    vector<node*> children;

    node(int val){
        data = val; // this->data = data
    }
    ~node(){
        for(int i = 0 ;i<children.size();i++){
            if(!children[i])
                delete children[i];
        }
    }
};
class GenericTree{
public:
    node* root; // line 3
    int size;
    
    GenericTree(vector<int> nums){
        stack<node*> st;
        size = 0;
        for(int i = 0;i<nums.size();i++){
            node *n = new node(nums[i]);
            if(i == 0){
                root = n;
                st.push(n);
                ++size;
            }else{
                if(n->data == -1){
                    st.pop();
                }else{
                    // cout << "In me" << endl;
                    st.top()->children.push_back(n);
                    st.push(n);
                    ++size;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    // tells us the number of nodes
    int getSize(){
        return size;
    }
};
int getSizeRecursive(const node* &root){ // line 1
    if(root->children.size()==0)
        return 1;

    int size = 0;
    for(const node* &child : root->children) // line 2
        size  += getSizeRecursive(child);
    return size+1;
}
int main(){
    #ifndef ONLINE_JUDGE
        freopen("input.txt","r",stdin);
        freopen("output.txt","w",stdout);
        freopen("error.txt","w",stderr);
    #endif
    vector<int> v{10,20,-1,30,50,-1,60,-1,-1,40,-1,-1};
    GenericTree t(v); // node that tree has been created 
    cout << t.size << endl;
    cout << getSizeRecursive(t.root) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

What i can understand from this is that compiler is not able to bind the `reference to pointer to const node` to `const pointer to node` but my question is that why it is taking `t.root` as `const pointer to node` whereas in actual it is just a `pointer to node`(see line no 3).

I am novice in c++. Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: The reason i have used `const* & root` is because i did not want to pass a copy of root to `getSizeRecursive` but during that since i have passed by reference i have used `const` so that this reference just only reads the root pointer and not modify it.

Comment: const node* const &child will work because your reference will be const either. But you'd better just use const node*.

Comment: @Greadimar my question is that why it is taking t.root as const pointer to node whereas in actual it is just a pointer to node

Comment: you take children from const pointer, so you can't use anything not const inside an object you are pointing to. So every function from vector will be used only with const aferwords. moreover when you use const p* item = vector, it will use operator [] const. Well technically not exactly operator [] const but a const iterator. But you should keep  the idea in mind

Comment: for(const p* item : vector )      <-to be more specific ranged for loop will try to use iterator begin() const method from a vector . You can see here how iterators are written [link] (https://stackoverflow.com/a/31457319/7804830)

Comment: *i have used const so that this reference just only reads the root pointer and not modify it* No you have not. The `const` in `const node* &` makes the pointed-to object const, but not the pointer. What you want is `node* const&`.

Comment: @j6t `node* const&` if i am not wrong this means that you are making a reference to `constant pointer to a node` and by `constant pointer to node` we mean that this pointer cannot change its address(that is we cannot point it to another node). Please correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: @Abhishekjha That's correct.

Comment: @j6t I have one more query, in `node* const& n` since pointer cannot point to another node but through reference i can change the value of the pointer as i have not declared this reference constant. If i want that that this reference also does not change the value stored in the pointer(which is the address of the node) i have to make this reference const as well maybe something like this `node* const const&n`. Am i even making sense?

Comment: @Abhishekjha When you have `T const& n`, you cannot change the value of type `T` whose name is `n`. Now, when `T` is `node*`, which is an address, then you cannot change the address named `n`. You do not need additional `const`s to make the address const (and there are no other addresses). OTOH, the address points to a `node`, and that you can change, because it is not-`const`. (But that is the node, not the address of the node.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's see the reason for getting each of the error on case by case basis. Moreover, i'll try to explain things in steps.

#### Case 1

Here we consider the 1st error due to the statement:

```
for(const node* &child : root->children)
```

Now to understand why we get error due to the above statement, let's understand the meaning of each term in step by step manner:

**Step 1:**

`root` is a ***non-const lvalue reference** to a non-const pointer to `const node`*. This means that we're allowed to change the pointer to which `root` refers(since we've a nonconst lvalue ref) but we're not allowed to change the actual `node` object to which that pointer is pointing.

**Step 2**

`root->children` is `const vector<node*>` since we're not allowed to change the `node` object to which the pointer is pointing as discussed in step 1 above. Basically, it is as if the pointed to object is itself `const` which in turn means its data members are treated as `const` as well. And as `children` is a data member so it is treated as `const` and thus `root->children` is `const vector<node*>`.

Note the conclusion of this step is that we have a const vector with elements of type `node*`.

**Step 3**

Now, `const node* &child` means that `child` is a *non-const lvalue reference to a **nonconst pointer** to a `const node`*. Again, this means that we're allowed to change the pointer residing inside the vector. But this is a problem because we learnt from step 2 above that we've a `const vector<node*>` meaning that we should not be allowed to change the pointer residing inside the vector. And hence you get the mentioned error.

##### Solution to case 1

To **solve** this you need to make sure that there is no way to change the pointer residing inside the `const vector` by adding a **low-level const** as shown below:

```
//-------vvvvv--------------------------->const added here
for(node*const &child : root->children)
```

The above works because now `child` is a *lvalue reference to a const pointer to a nonconst node object*.

#### Case 2

Here we consider the 2nd error due to the expression:

```
getSizeRecursive(t.root)
```

Here the passed argument `t.root` is a `node*` while the parameter is a `const node* &`. Now, the passed argument is implicitly convertible to `const node*` but result of that conversion will be an rvalue. But since the parameter `root` is an ***nonconst lvalue reference** to a non-const pointer to const node* it cannot be bound to an rvalue.

This is basically the same error that you will get using:

```
node *ptr;
const node*& ref = ptr; //will produce the same error saying: error: cannot bind non-const lvalue reference of type ‘const int*&’ to an rvalue of type ‘const int*’
```

##### Solution to Case 2

Basically, a given type `T` can be bound to `T&` or `T const&` while a given type `const T` can be bound to `T const&`. And in your example, the passed argument is `node*` meaning it can be bound to both `node*&` as well as `node*const&`.

To solve this you can make the lvalue reference to a const lvalue reference as shown below:

```
node *ptr;
//---vvvvv--------------->const added here
node*const& ref = ptr;
```

In your example, this means:

```
//------------------------vvvvv--------->const added here
int getSizeRecursive(node*const &root){ // line 1
```

[Working demo](https://onlinegdb.com/7RTsfKTB1V)

Comment: @Abhishekjha Glad i could be of help. You're welcome :)