# c++ range-for loop over custom class ::begin() expects 1 argument, 0 provided

Tags: c++, c++11

I am following an example in *section 7.2* of *A Tour of C++* where I have a class which I want to iterate over in a range-for loop.

First, I have the parent.

```cpp
template<typename T>
class Container {
    public:
        virtual T& operator[](int i) const = 0; 
        virtual int size() const = 0; 
        virtual ~Container() {} 
};
```

Second, I define the class itself. I define `begin` and `end` in order to iterate over the class in a range-for loop.

```cpp
template<typename T>
class MyVector: public Container<T> {
public:
    explicit MyVector(int s); 
    MyVector(std::initializer_list<double>);
    T& operator[](int i) const override {
        if (i<0 || i>size()) throw std::out_of_range{"Anatoly's Vector operator []"};
        return elem[i];
        }
auto begin(MyVector<T>& x) -> T* const {return &x[0];}
auto end(MyVector<T>& x) -> T* const {return &x[0] + x.size();}
protected: 
    T* elem; 
    int sz;
```

Define the constructors:

```cpp
template<typename T>
MyVector<T>::MyVector(int s) 
    :elem{new T[s]}, sz{s} // initialize members
{
    std::cout << "Default constructor called" << std::endl;
}

template<typename T>
MyVector<T>::MyVector(std::initializer_list<double> lst) // initialize with a list
:elem{new T[lst.size()]}, sz{static_cast<int>(lst.size())}
{
    std::copy(lst.begin(),lst.end(),elem); 
}
template<typename T>
auto MyVector<T>::size() const -> int { 
    return sz;
};
```

Finally, this is how I intend to use it:

```cpp
void write2(MyVector<std::string>& vs) // Vector of some strings
{
    for (auto& s: vs) 
        std::cout << s << '\n';
}
```

**But this doesn't compile**. I get this compiler error:

```
In function 'void write2(MyVector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >&)':
no matching function for call to 'MyVector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >::begin()'
for (auto& s: vs)
note: candidate: 'T* MyVector<T>::begin(MyVector<T>&) [with T = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>]'
candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
```

What am I doing wrong? Why candidate expects 1 argument, but 0 provided? How do I fix this?

EDIT:
As commentators kindly suggested, `begin` should not take arguments, which explains the error message. I have misinterpreted the book, where `begin` is defined outside of the class:
[image]

Comment: You wrote your begin to take a parameter. You shouldn't be surprised that it expects one. However, that's an incorrect way to implement begin. It is a member function, and therefore only cares about the calling object. Why would you want the ability to get the beginning of any arbirtary object from any other object?

Comment: The tour, while a good book, is intended for people already familiar with one language. It's important to understand the differences. Python, for example, requires a class method pass `self` as the first parameter. This is not the case in C++. Member functions in C++ are already aware of the "calling object."

Comment: oh wow! But this is what the book does! Must be typo then.

Comment: Does the book really do that? Can you please take a photo of the page where it does that and include in your question? And does the book have an errata, showing problems? Is this listed as a problem there?

Comment: To your edit, it's interesting that they define begin as not-a-member.

Comment: I've added a snippet. In the book `begin` is defined outside of the class. It takes an argument, but it must be the case that as @sweenish pointed out - that argument is somewhat like `self` argument. ie inside the class it is implicitly there.

Comment: Either, **free** function `template <typename T>auto begin(MyVector<T>&)`, nor **member** function `template <typename T> auto MyVector<T>::begin()`.

Comment: The book is using free functions while you are using member functions.  Member functions don't need a parameter as they have `this`.

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31457319/12002570) in the dupe: [How to make my custom type to work with "range-based for loops"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8164567/how-to-make-my-custom-type-to-work-with-range-based-for-loops) that explains everything in detail.