# Items in QMap get lost

Tags: c++, qt

I have a XML-file holding among other things some groups with name and userlists. In my code in constructor I have set a dictionary for this list:

```
dictGroups= QMap<QString, QList<QString>>() ;
```

In headerfile it is declared as

```
public:
QMap<QString, QList<QString>> dictGroups;
```

Then I read the file: `ReadConfig();`

```
void AppConfig::ReadConfig(void)
{
    ...
while(!reader.atEnd())
{
    ReadGroups(reader);
    if (dictGroups.isEmpty()) qDebug()<<"ReadConfig_isEmpty";
}
    ...
```

This is my ReadGroups:

```
void AppConfig::ReadGroups(QXmlStreamReader &reader)
{
    dictGroups.clear();
    while(!reader.atEnd())
    {
        reader.readNext();
        if (reader.error())
        {
...
        }
        else
        {
            if (reader.isStartElement())
            {
                if (reader.name().toString().toLower()=="group"){
                    ReadGroup(reader);
                    if (dictGroups.isEmpty()) qDebug()<<"ReadGroups_isEmpty";
                }
            }
            else if (reader.isEndElement())
            {
                if (reader.name().toString().toLower() == "groups")
                {
                    if(dictGroups.count()<=0){
                        QList<QString> users= QList<QString>();
                        users.append(this->GetUsername());
                        dictGroups.insert("admin", users);
                    }
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My problem is, that the items inserted in dictGroups while ReadGroups get lost. I get the **debug output**

> ReadConfig_isEmpty

but in ReadGroups seems everything is ok.
I'm at a loss, puzzling around for hours, can anybody help to find the reason?

Comment: Are you absolutely positive that you insert anything into `dictGroups`?

Comment: Yes :-(  My debug prints me insert messages and ReadGroups_isEmpty will not be written. Also it doesn't insert the 'admin' -user, if dict would be empty, because at this step it isn't empty.

Comment: Difficult to say anything without an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org).

Comment: just a comment: the line in the constructor does nothing useful and can be removed (the `dictGroups= QMap<QString, QList<QString>>() ;`)

Comment: I thought the purpose of a map was to *find* things, not lose them!

Comment: @KarstenKoop removed the line and it works anyway. There I have a problem in understanding. I only declare it and not have to initialize it ?

Comment: The default constructor of the member variable is called automatically. What you were doing is create a new instance of `QMap` and assign it to your instance, which copies the contents ([see `operator =`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmap.html#operator-eq)), but both maps are empty.

Comment: @rubenvb If I ever get enough reputation to upvote, you'll get my first for being so lucky ;-)

Comment: @KarstenKoop Is it because its a value type? Reference Types I have to initialize with operater =. The difference between value and reference types I've learned few days ago having a similar problem with QList. So I was insecure. So maybe the question is really off-topic. Nevertheless for me the correspondence was very helpful. Thanks!

Comment: I guess you are mixing up Java/C# with C++

Comment: @KarstenKoop Yes, C# is my 'home' , and if I have to do sth. with c++ coming to my personally pointer hell ;-) won't to querrel, I'll get on with it.

Comment: @rubenvb +1 I got it :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have this code:

```
dictGroups.clear();
```

Why do you expect the `dictGroups` to persist when you clear them on every iteration of the outer loop? Don't do that.

The `clear` statement belongs perhaps at the beginning of `ReadConfig`.

Your method name capitalizations are very much out of place in Qt code, though: capitalized names are by convention reserved for groups.

Comment: You're right, the method ReadGroups is called a second time when coming through the xml-end-tag, a stupid mistake, thank you a lot.

Comment: ever thought, formatting my code is "matter of taste", now I looked for a regulation but found this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1776291/2747431)